# How to add LangVersion 8.0 to project file?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using visual studio 2019 community.

I tried to add to the .csproj file the line :

```
<LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
```

Inside the PropertyGroup like this :

```
</PropertyGroup>
<LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
```

but since i changed it and added the langversion line i can't compile the project and run it at all.

i can make right click on the solution and select reload project and it will reload the project but with the same error on the Exception?

Where should i add the line : 8.0   ?

Comment: That is not "inside the PropertyGroup", that is after a property group.

Comment: [C# language versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version)